# Why would you use Assert.ReplaceNullChars(string input)?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, assert

Why would you use the following?

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert.ReplaceNullChars(string input)
```

I have searched but can't find any cases of anyone really using this.  Even MSDN is not helpful.  All I can find out about it is:

> ReplaceNullChars – Replaces Null characters in a string \0 with \\0

This doesn't sound all that useful to me and I'm suprised it's there in the Assert class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s probably so that you can print a string containing null chars for better diagnostics, since printing a string which contains a null char usually doesn’t result in anything meaningful (it will usually be truncated in the output).

However, a better method would have been `Assert.EscapeNonprintableChars` – i.e. replace not only `\0` but all non-printable characters.

Answer (score 1):

The [current version of the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.replacenullchars?view=mstest-net-1.2.0) notes:

> **Remarks**
>
> This is only public and still present to preserve compatibility with the V1 framework.

Apparently, this method was made public by mistake, and they can't hide it now without breaking backwards compatibility.